# Using IFS and REGEXMATCH Fails

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to use the following `IFS` statement

```
=IFS(REGEXMATCH(B2,"football"),"brown",REGEXMATCH(B2,"baseball"),"white")
```

but Google Sheets keeps saying the syntax is wrong. What is wrong with this?

Column `B` is a text column.

Other similar posts did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The formula works fine.
You probably need to change it (depending on your locale) to:

```
=IFS(REGEXMATCH(D2;"football");"brown";REGEXMATCH(D2;"baseball");"white")
```

Another improvement you may make is to wrap it in the `IFNA` function

```
=IFNA(IFS(REGEXMATCH(D2,"football"),"brown",REGEXMATCH(D2,"baseball"),"white"),"No match")
```